# Chess Position Trainer on Linux or Minimax on Linux

Tags: linux, minimax

Chess Position Trainer allows you to do leaf node evaluation and then minimax the results after that. Is it possible to install Chess Position Trainer on Linux? (I tried under mine, but couldn't), or is there any other software for Linux that can do minimax nodes?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, no. Chess Position Trainer only runs on Windows 7, 8, and 10.

See the system requirements [here](http://www.chesspositiontrainer.com/index.php/en/download).

You could consider a virtual machine running Windows on a Linux host, but it will not run natively.

Comment: Ok, so only in Windows :( ,  but is it possible use syzygy in CPT ?, I can't find option to set up it in engine settings.

Comment: I just looked through the manual, and I did not see anything either. It might be because they seem more focused on the opening, and thus, it would not be relevant. You can always email them, and ask. Don't shoot the messenger. :)

Answer (score 4):

I have not tried it, but you might be able to install Chess Position Trainer under Linux using WINE.  I haven't looked at WINE in a long time, but it's apparently a lot better than it was ~10 years ago when I last tried to do anything with it.

Comment: I tried wine, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are oodles of programs for linux.  Take your choice.

Stockfish runs on linux.  And many other places too. 
It is open source so you can modify the code to do what you want.

These are rated 'best' chess aps for Linux:
PyChess Advanced chess client following the GNOME Human Interface Guidelines   /////

Cute Chess  Graphical user interface, command-line interface and library   /////

Raptor  Chess interface for freechess.org (FICS) /////

Stockfish   Strong open source chess engine /////

Crafty  Highly competent chess engine  /////

Scid    Shane's Chess Information Database /////

SOSS    Chess pairing software /////

ChessDB Based on Scid with some enhancements /////

Jin Java based graphical client for internet chess servers /////

jose    Database with a graphical front-end for viewing and editing games /////

Knights Chess game for the KDE desktop environment /////

Xiphos  UCI chess engine with modern search techniques and multithreading /////

SCID and ChessX run on Linux as does SCIDvsPC

There are many fine engines for LINUX.
Stockfish and Critter are popular with one reviewer.

Comment: That is not what he is looking for though. He wants something akin to this http://www.chesspositiontrainer.com/index.php/en/

Comment: alas that did not show up in linux chess software lists.  he can use a browser in linux to access web sites with various training for chess.   and .the software noted CAN DO minimax modes he asked for.

Comment: I noticed that only pay chess softwares have minimax. Probably it is difficult to do it for programmers.